# Saving bitarrays in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, bitarray, database

I'm building Bloom filters at my company and need to serialize and save them into a MongoDB. The document structure I'm currently using looks like this:

```
{
    '_id': unique ID,
    'm': number of bits in Bloom filter,
    'n': capacity of Bloom filter,
    'k': number of hashes,
    'bitarray': a string of the Bloom filter’s bitarray,
    'seeds': a list of seeds for the k hashes
}
```

As you can see, the bitarray is currently represented as a string and Bloom filter bitarrays can get *huge* for a larger capacity. A single document in my database is around **5 megabytes** right now which is terrible.

If it helps in anyway, I am programming in Python and using PyMongo as an adapter.

I certainly believe this is not the right way to save bitarrays and I can't find help elsewhere on the internet. Help me out please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out I could use the BSON binary data type to get my work done.
To serialize my Bloom filter objects, I did this:

```
from bson.binary import Binary

obj = BloomFilter()
serialized = obj.__dict__.copy()
serialized['bitarray'] = Binary(obj.bitarray.tobytes())
```

Please note that bitarray is the Python [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) library and not `BitString`. The final dictionary `serialized` was easy to insert into a MongoDB.

Hope this helps out anyone looking for this.
Cheers :)